# MessageBox in qt and custom icon on a frame

Tags: qt

Is there a way to specify an icon which appears on the frame of the dialog? I'm not talking about the icon inside this window, but about the icon on actual frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`QWidget::setWindowIcon()`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowIcon-prop).